# Locale that defaults to LATIN1 Encoding

Tags: postgresql, encoding, locale, latin1

I'm trying to create a new database cluster in postgresql that defaults to LATIN1 encoding, or at least supports it. Does anybody know what locale I could use? I am on Windows 7 64bit

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out with help from a friend. I can use:

English_Sweden.28591

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default encoding, you have to create a new `template1` database. This database serves as template for creating new databases. Drop the current one and [create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html) a new one using `template0` and use the correct encoding, latin1 in your case.

```
UPDATE pg_database 
  SET datistemplate = false -- otherwise you can't drop this database
  WHERE datname = 'template1'; 

DROP DATABASE template1;

CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH 
  TEMPLATE template0
  ENCODING LATIN1;
```

Check all settings for template1 before you drop this database, maybe you want these in your new template1 as well.

Comment: I'm not quite at this step yet. I can't create a database(or template1 database)  with encoding LATIN1 because my current locale does not support LATIN1 encoding. What I'm trying to do is create a new database cluster with a locale that supports LATIN1. I don't know what locale to use though.

Comment: When doing this in Linux, I use --locale=en_CA.ISO-8859-1 . This doesn't seem to be available for me though in windows.